# RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #3 'index'

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I'm experimenting with argumentation mining with BERT and try to identify argument components (BIO-classification task). I closely followed the code from this article, [Named Entity Recognition With Bert](https://www.depends-on-the-definition.com/named-entity-recognition-with-bert), but adapted it to fit my data. I run the code on colab (hardware accelerator is set to GPU).

Does anybody know a solution to my problem? Thanks in advance!

```
epochs = 5
max_grad_norm = 1.0

for _ in trange(epochs, desc="Epoch"):
    # TRAIN loop
    model.train()
    tr_loss = 0
    nb_tr_examples, nb_tr_steps = 0, 0
    for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        # add batch to gpu
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch
        # forward pass
        loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
        # backward pass
        loss.backward()
        # track train loss
        tr_loss += loss.item()
        nb_tr_examples += b_input_ids.size(0)
        nb_tr_steps += 1
        # gradient clipping
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(parameters=model.parameters(), max_norm=max_grad_norm)
        # update parameters
        optimizer.step()
        model.zero_grad()
    # print train loss per epoch
    print("Train loss: {}".format(tr_loss/nb_tr_steps))
    # VALIDATION on validation set
    model.eval()
    eval_loss, eval_accuracy = 0, 0
    nb_eval_steps, nb_eval_examples = 0, 0
    predictions , true_labels = [], []
    for batch in valid_dataloader:
        batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
        b_input_ids, b_input_mask, b_labels = batch

        with torch.no_grad():
            tmp_eval_loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None,
                                  attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
            logits = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None,
                           attention_mask=b_input_mask)
        logits = logits.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label_ids = b_labels.to('cpu').numpy()
        predictions.extend([list(p) for p in np.argmax(logits, axis=2)])
        true_labels.append(label_ids)

        tmp_eval_accuracy = flat_accuracy(logits, label_ids)

        eval_loss += tmp_eval_loss.mean().item()
        eval_accuracy += tmp_eval_accuracy

        nb_eval_examples += b_input_ids.size(0)
        nb_eval_steps += 1
    eval_loss = eval_loss/nb_eval_steps
    print("Validation loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
    print("Validation Accuracy: {}".format(eval_accuracy/nb_eval_steps))
    pred_tags = [tags_vals[p_i] for p in predictions for p_i in p]
    valid_tags = [tags_vals[l_ii] for l in true_labels for l_i in l for l_ii in l_i]
    print("F1-Score: {}".format(f1_score(pred_tags, valid_tags)))
```

Although I closely followed the original code, it does not seem to work for me and I keep on getting this mistake...

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-aa659bbf8fac> in <module>()
     12 
     13         # forward pass
---> 14         loss = model(b_input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=b_input_mask, labels=b_labels)
     15         # backward pass
     16         loss.backward()

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1465         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   1466         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 1467     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   1468 
   1469 

RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #3 'index'
```

**SOLUTION**:
setting model = model.to(device) plus reducing the batch size from 32 to 4 allowed the program to run without any runtimeerrors.

Comment: Set model.to(device) in front of your code and let use know.

Comment: This return another runtime error:
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 192.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.17 GiB total capacity; 10.66 GiB already allocated; 139.81 MiB free; 54.26 MiB cached)

Comment: restart your kernel then and try again, everything should go either to device = cuda or device = cpu